# QSharedMemory and QLocalSocket: performance questions

Tags: multithreading, performance, ipc, qt5, qlocalsocket

I'm looking for IPC with high performance in Qt (v5.3) on Windows.
In my final situation, I will have 3 (or more) producer process and one consumer process.

Before that, I made some tests using 1 producer thread and 1 consumer thread, using both [QLocalSocket/QLocalServer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlocalsocket.html) ([example](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Qt_IPC_using_QLocalSocket_%26_QLocalServer)) and [QSharedMemory](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsharedmemory.html) ([example](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/QSharedMemory_example/)), and I have been surprised that the times are comparable.

In particular I got the following results (from first message till last message received):

Sending/Writing 1000 string message:   QSharedMemory: 1020ms,  QLocalSocket 1010ms
Sending/Writing 5000 string message:   QSharedMemory: 5010ms,  QLocalSocket 5090ms
Sending/Writing 10000 string message:  QSharedMemory: 10097ms, QLocalSocket 10850ms

The questions are:

- Do you agree with this results or I probably wrong something in my code ?
- Are there some IPC methods with better performance in Qt ?

Thanks in advance.
arthur86

**UPDATE 23/10/2014**

I take more time to investigate about this doubt, and I found a reasonable response.
I discover that a big percentage of the previous time is used by context switch between thread. In particular, if I remove Thread::msleep(0); at the end of each cycle I'm able to reach lower computational time.

Eg.

- 1000 string message:   less than 100ms both for QLocalSocket and QSharedMemory
- 5000 string message:   less than 300ms both for QLocalSocket and QSharedMemory
- 10000 string message:  less than 1000ms both for QLocalSocket and QSharedMemory

I think removing `Thread::msleep(0)` is no a good idea. Isn't it ?
Could you suggest me some methods to improve performance with sleep instruction ?

Comment: Why would you wish to sleep your thread when pretty much every modern processor is dual core at last? We will not be able to do much without some code.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira I'm sorry, but the application will be deployed in embedded system with single core CPU. The code I used is the same of the linked examples.

Comment: Interesting! Using an event driven approach wouldn't be better? So the task will still sleep, and wake only when there is work to do? This way I believe you will get as few context switches as possible.

Comment: I think this is possible in case of threads worker, I don't know if it's possible to do that between processes.

Comment: I don't have an example for this [my Google skills seems not enough...], but I believe with `QSharedMemory` and `QSystemSemaphore` is possible. Take a look at the `QSharedMemory.lock()` method, it will lock the shared memory region (oh! really??), while `QSystemSemaphore` may provide a counter for how many "messages" are pending.

Comment: is there some general guideline / pro/con when to use QLocalSocket and when QSharedMemory?